# Remove special characters from string such as smileys but keep german special charactes

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, ascii, python-module-unicodedata

I know how to remove unwanted charactes in a string, like smileys etc. However, some languages like german have special charactes, too.

This is my current code:

```
import unicodedata
string = "süß "
uni_str = str(unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', \
           string).encode('ascii','ignore'))
```

Is there the possibillity to keep the german special characters bu delete the other unwanted charactes, such as smileys like ? so that `uni_str` will hold the letters "süß" at the end?

Curently, the smileys will get deleted, but the german characters will either be transformed in other vocals or deletet, too.

The smileys in the example are just exemplary and can be any kind of unwanted character.

I am using Python 3.6 and Windows 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something simple like this (just add the German letters):

```
def filter_characters(self, value):
    allowed_characters = " 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    return ''.join(c for c in value if c in allowed_characters )
```

**Edit**:

Another possibilty is to create the allowed_characters with the help of the string module:

```
import string
allowed_characters = string.printable + 'öäüß'
```

Comment: this seems like workaround, but this would also mean to include every special character which is coded in ascii, like "!"§$%&/()=?,;.:-_" etc. ? Is there maybe the possiblity to get the allowed characte from a kind of charset and then extend it to the german ones?

Comment: using a `set` would probably speed things up here.

Comment: +1 to using a set instead of a string/list to keep O(1) lookups (even though the string of allowed characters is short)

Comment: Yes, I do agree that a set would be a ton faster.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which characters are special or otherwise unwanted in your world, but maybe removing all characters with a "Symbol, Other" property is something useful:

```
import unicodedata as ud

def remove_symbols(text):
    return ''.join(c for c in text if ud.category(c) != 'So')
```

This will keep any letters, digits, punctuation symbols, and white space characters, so the following example won't lose the fancy quotes or the "é":

```
>>> remove_symbols('Was für ein «süßes» Café! ')
'Was für ein «süßes» Café! '
```

Have a look at the available categories on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property) or search for it on unicode.org.